# Unit testing using Eclipse - JUNIT

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, testing, junit

I wrote an android application that uses GPS mainly, using Eclipse.

I want to do a `JUNIT` test for the application.

What is the best way for specifying multiple values for my unit tests?

Answer (score 0):

In each Test you should use one of the many available asserts http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html to check whether the value returned by the tested method is the correct one. while testing the method you can pass any parameters you need to it.

for instance

```
 assertEquals("OK",myObj.methodUnderTest(param1,param2,param3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood the question, but it sounds like you want parameterized tests. This allows you to write one test but test several different values against that one test.

I'm more familiar with NUnit's parameterized unit tests, but [here's a link](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) to JUnit's documentation on parameterized unit tests.